# Density of Multivariate Normal Distribution (MVN): Dimension = 1 or k?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have a very naive question about the density function of the MVN distribution. According to the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), the density function formula sometimes has a constant `k` (dimension of the MVN variables) and sometimes not. For example, see the PDF on the right-hand side on the wike page, it has no `k`, whereas, see the PDF in the middle part, it has a `k`.

To be specific, I wrote a R function for the MVN and tested against `mvtnorm::dmvnorm`:

```
dmvnormal <- function(x,mu,sigma, log = FALSE){
  m = t(x-mu)
  h = m%*%solve(sigma)%*%t(m)
  k = 1 # <-------------------------------------- use 1 or k??
  logp = -log(sqrt(det((2*pi)^k*sigma))) - h[1]/2
  if (log) return(logp)
  else return(exp(logp))
}
x = c(0.4,0.6)
mu = rep(0,length(x))
sigma = diag(length(x))
a = dmvnormal(x, mu = mu, sigma = sigma, log = FALSE)

# compared with mvtnorm package
b = mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x,mean=mu,sigma=sigma)
identical(a,b)
```

It seems by default `k=1`. So why the `k` is sometimes expressed in the PDF formula?

Comment: Isn’t the dimension $k$ implied by the length of $\mu$ (equal to the length of the diagonal of $\Sigma$)?

Comment: Yes. I am curious about why `k` sometimes does not appear (i.e., k=1) and sometimes does (i.e., k=length(x)). The mvtnorm package looks using k=1, which is equal to ignoring `k` in the PDF formula.

Comment: This probability density function here is $\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ so takes a $k$ dimensional point and gives a $1$ dimensional density value for that point.  There is a different dimensional issue if $\det(\Sigma)=0$, i.e. $\Sigma^{-1}$ does not exist, and then there is no density in this sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the Wikipedia article, the two expressions you refer to are, first:

$$\det(2\pi\Sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp (-\frac{1}{2}(x - \mu)^{T} \Sigma^{-1}(x - \mu) )$$

And, second:

$$\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (x-\mu)^T{\Sigma}^{-1}(x-\mu)\right)}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k |\Sigma|}}$$

But, determinants have a homogeneity property, such that, for any $k$ by $k$ matrix $A$ and a scalar constant $c$, we have that:

$$\det(cA) = c^k \det(A)$$

So then:

$$\det(2\pi\Sigma) = (2\pi)^k \det(\Sigma)$$

Therefore, they are equivalent formulations. In your implementation, you've put $2\pi$ inside the determinant, so there shouldn't be a $k$.